# Can't reference stuff in ListView's highlight

Tags: listview, reference, qml

Like the title said, I'm having an issue where I have a `ListView`, with the usual `delegate` and a `highlight`.

Inside my highlight I've placed a `Text` component with `id` so I can reference it.

So behaviour should be like, I move trough the `ListView`'s items, and when I press a number on my keyboard, the text inside the `highlight`should display it.

But any time I try to do anything with the aforementioned `Text` component (reference it by `id`, like `textComponent.text = "123"` I get a `ReferenceError: textComponent is not defined`.

I've gone trough the documentation but didn't find anything related to not being able to get to highlight's contents by `id`.

Does someone have a clue what could is the cause for this, or such a behaviour is simply not supported?

I didn't include any code since the problem is easily explained and reproduced, but if someone needs it, i'll gladly include a short snippet of the thing.

**EDIT**
The code

```
  ListView
    {
        height: 500
        width: 500

        model: ListModel { id: channelListModel }

        highlightMoveDuration: 200
        highlightRangeMode: ListView.ApplyRange
        snapMode: ListView.SnapToItem

        preferredHighlightBegin: height * 0.2
        preferredHighlightEnd: height * 0.8

        delegate: Item
        {
            id: channelItem
            width: ListView.view.width * 0.96
            height: parent.height

            Text
                {
                    anchors.fill: parent
                    text: "generic row text"
                }
        }

        Keys.onPressed:
        {
            switch(event.key)
            {
                case Qt.Key_0:
                case Qt.Key_1:
                case Qt.Key_2:
                case Qt.Key_3:
                case Qt.Key_4:
                case Qt.Key_5:
                case Qt.Key_6:
                case Qt.Key_7:
                case Qt.Key_8:
                case Qt.Key_9:
                    textComponent.text = event.key
             }
         }

        highlight: Rectangle
        {
            id: highlight
            color: "#40ffffff"

            Text
                {
                    id: textComponent
                    anchors.fill: parent
                }
         }
```

Comment: Do you have some code example?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you look in the documentation of the `ListView` you will discover that the [type of the property `highlight`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtquick-listview.html#highlight-prop) is `Component`.

A `Component` always creates a new context for the `id`s like it would be in another file.
This means, you can't access `id`s inside a `Component` from the outside. The Component might have been instantiated multiple times or never at all - so the `id` would not be unique.

**What can you do?**

Create a `property` in the `ListView` and read that from within the component.

```
ListView {
    id: myListView
    ...
    property string hightlightText

    highlight: SomeItem { // Will be automatically transformed in a Component and initaly not fully created
        Text {
            text: myListView.highlightText // You can reference ids of the 'outside world'
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Ah I see. I've used `Text` as an example here, in reality I have a component with a function I have to call from outside, so I've put a `signal` in `ListView` and triggered it with keyPress, then used a `Connections` from the highlight to listen for it. But your comment illustrated the issue perfectly, so thanks!